# "CELLIMAGE" text displayed in place of image upon export pdf script from Google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hi there those way cleverer than me!

I have a Google script to export a pdf from a Google sheet which works fine. However I have an image in a cell that is not displayed in the exported pdf, instead it just says "CELLIMAGE". If I manually export the pdf it displays the image correctly...

[image]

[image]

My code is:

```
function exportFl() {

var sheetName = "FL" 
//var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
//var allsheets = ss.getSheets();
//for (var s in allsheets){
//var sheet=allsheets[s]
//var maxRows = ss.getMaxRows(); 
//var lastRow = ss.getLastRow();
//if (maxRows-lastRow != 0){
//ss.deleteRows(lastRow+1, maxRows-lastRow);}

var value = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName).getRange('E7').getValue();
var folderID = "1x0tBqOP07e2XIzXHgvYqAaBiu7Zd7DfV"; // Folder id to save in a folder.

var timeZone = Session.getScriptTimeZone();
date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timeZone, "YYMMdd");

var pdfName = value+"_FSL Conformance_"+ date;

var sourceSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var sourceSheet = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);
var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);

//Copy whole spreadsheet
var destSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.open(DriveApp.getFileById(sourceSpreadsheet.getId()).makeCopy("tmp_convert_to_pdf", folder))

//delete redundant sheets
var sheets = destSpreadsheet.getSheets();
for (i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
if (sheets[i].getSheetName() != sheetName){
destSpreadsheet.deleteSheet(sheets[i]);
}
}

var destSheet = destSpreadsheet.getSheets()[0];
//repace cell values with text (to avoid broken references) 
var sourceRange = sourceSheet.getRange(1,1,sourceSheet.getMaxRows(),sourceSheet.getMaxColumns());
var sourcevalues = sourceRange.getValues();
var destRange = destSheet.getRange(1, 1, destSheet.getMaxRows(), destSheet.getMaxColumns());
destRange.setValues(sourcevalues);

//save to pdf

// --- I added below script.
var r = destSheet.getDataRange();
var startRow = r.getNumRows() + 1;
var number = destSheet.getMaxRows() - startRow + 1;
if (number > 0) destSheet.deleteRows(startRow, number);
SpreadsheetApp.flush(); // This might not be required to be used.
// ---

var theBlob = destSpreadsheet.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf').setName(pdfName);
var newFile = folder.createFile(theBlob);

//Delete the temporary sheet
DriveApp.getFileById(destSpreadsheet.getId()).setTrashed(true);
}
```

Anyone got any ideas??

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that in your script, the cells are overwritten by `destRange.setValues(sourcevalues);`. I thought that this might be the reason of your issue. And, in your script, the values have already been copied by `var destSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.open(DriveApp.getFileById(sourceSpreadsheet.getId()).makeCopy("tmp_convert_to_pdf", folder))`. So in this case, how about the following modification?

In this modification, I used the following flow.

1. Copy the 1st tab.
2. Overwrite the data to the copied sheet.
3. Copy the images in the cells to the copied sheet.
4. Delete the temporal sheet.

When this flow is reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

##### From:

```
var destSheet = destSpreadsheet.getSheets()[0];
//repace cell values with text (to avoid broken references) 
var sourceRange = sourceSheet.getRange(1,1,sourceSheet.getMaxRows(),sourceSheet.getMaxColumns());
var sourcevalues = sourceRange.getValues();
var destRange = destSheet.getRange(1, 1, destSheet.getMaxRows(), destSheet.getMaxColumns());
destRange.setValues(sourcevalues);
```

##### To:

```
var tempSheet = destSpreadsheet.getSheets()[0];

// 1. Copy the 1st tab.
var destSheet = tempSheet.copyTo(destSpreadsheet);

// 2. Overwrite the data to the copied sheet.
var sourceRange = sourceSheet.getRange(1, 1, sourceSheet.getMaxRows(), sourceSheet.getMaxColumns());
var sourcevalues = sourceRange.getValues();
var destRange = destSheet.getRange(1, 1, destSheet.getMaxRows(), destSheet.getMaxColumns());
destRange.setValues(sourcevalues);

// 3. Copy the images in the cells to the copied sheet.
sourcevalues.forEach((r, i) => {
  r.forEach((c, j) => {
    if (c.toString() == "CellImage") {
      tempSheet.getRange(i + 1, j + 1).copyTo(destSheet.getRange(i + 1, j + 1), {contentsOnly: true}); // Modified
    }
  });
});

// 4. Delete the temporal sheet.
destSpreadsheet.deleteSheet(tempSheet);
```

#### References:

- [copyTo(spreadsheet) of Class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#copytospreadsheet)
- [copyTo(destination) of Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination)

Comment: Thanks Tanaike, 
That works, the only problem is it squeezes the image into cell F12 by the look of it, whereas originally the image is in merged cells from F12-G14...

Comment: @Jon Bowles Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `the only problem is it squeezes the image into cell F12 by the look of it, whereas originally the image is in merged cells from F12-G14`. So, in order to correctly understand about your current issue, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet for replicating the issue? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: No problem :) I just mean the layout of the image:  from the sheet to the pdf is different. I have added your change in the exportSg.gs
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/117IyvIvaYPVvFMxv8wz8kaojrm81BVynhSxgYp0Yfsw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @Jon Bowles Thank you for replying and providing sample Spreadsheet. From your additional information, I updated my answer. I modified `tempSheet.getRange(i + 1, j + 1).copyTo(destSheet.getRange(i + 1, j + 1));` to `tempSheet.getRange(i + 1, j + 1).copyTo(destSheet.getRange(i + 1, j + 1), {contentsOnly: true});`. Could you please confirm it?